# nodejs express: compression of response doesn't work

Tags: node.js, http, express, compression, gzip

I'm trying to serve compressed views with NodeJS/Express.

Even if I configured properly the app, there is no trace of compression. Only static file are compressed.

If I access a view in Chrome, I cannot find the field `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

The following is configuration of my Express app:

```
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(expressValidator());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    app.use(express.staticCache());
    app.use(gzippo.staticGzip( path.join(__dirname, 'public') ,{maxAge:86400000} ));
    app.use(gzippo.compress());
    //app.use(express.compress());

    app.use(app.router);
```

Note that I'm using gzippo for compression. However also the basic compression `express.compress()` doesn't work.

Comment: why are you using gzippo? it doesn't support node 0.10

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308588/10030693

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move compress to be the first item after `view item`. Also, be sure to clear cache before checking the Chrome network tag to look for the Encoding header.

Comment: But **why** must compress be before everything else?

Comment: I understand the view will have been served before it could be compressed: http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.use
"The order of which middleware are "defined" using app.use() is very important, they are invoked sequentially, thus this defines middleware precedence."

...I'm trying to figure out how to use compression in Express 4 myself...

Comment: I was trying to figure out for the life of me why my content-type was not being set. If you clear the cache in Chrome, the content-type is set correctly. Thank you for this.

Comment: Weird, in the chrome network tab it shows me `Content-Encoding:gzip` but with every gzip test tool it shows me that there is no gzip compression. http://checkgzipcompression.com/
Any ideas which tool I should believe?
Ok, googles tool tells me yes:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/