# How to decompress Gzip Json response via Axios

Tags: json, axios, compression, gzip, response

I am using  Axios to get the JSON response from the web server. The response is in  compressed gzip format. How can I decompress the response and get the Json Data.

Comment: See the bottom of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308588/10030693

Answer (score 9):

axios has a decompress option. No need to decompress it manually:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', 'decompress': true })
```

Also, your server should never sent compressed content if your Accept-Encoding header does not contain gzip (or any other compression format).

Comment: Axios sends an accept-encoding header of 'gzip, deflate, br' by default because browsers normally decompress the response but that creates problems with node where that's not the case.

Answer (score 8):

```
const zlib = require('zlib')

let url = "https://example.com/GZ_FILE.gz"

const { data } = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })

zlib.gunzip(data, function (_err, output) {
    console.log(output.toString())
  })
```