# Get my IOS installations and other app store data

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, axios, app-store

I'm trying to get the number of installs of my IOS application but failed.

1. I tried using `api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/`, with the query of

   ```
   res = await axios.get
         ('https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter\[frequency\]=MONTHLY&filter[reportDate]=2020-12&filter\[reportSubType\]=SUMMARY&filter\[reportType\]=SALES&filter\[vendorNumber\]=******'
         ,{
           headers: {
             Accept:'application/a-gzip, application/json',
             Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token //the token is a variable which holds the token
           }
         })

   console.log(res.data)
   ```

   and finally managed to get a response but the response is of type application/a-gzip
   so I don't know how to read it.

   Looks like -

   ```
   ՓQo�0ǟo��O{���(�*Z��A�g
   ��*��}0���&ɲ�l�ʢU����|���iՋ5d�Ū��w�Y@�=6���BP��Dm��.��*bŮE��(I���ZHA��l\�Xõ�,)  �^�{#�
                                                                                     ����i������E��{����霨m�W�iQ�۪}~V�t�=6�M�EKC
   ```
2. Using itunesconnectanalytics, using this npm library I finally manage to get the info, but I don't know what to do with the 2-factor authentication once I upload my code to the could (AWS Fargate)

If anyone has a solution for any of the cases or other tips it would be amazing,
Thanks

Comment: Check the answer of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882796/how-to-decompress-gzip-json-response-via-axios

Comment: I tried it and the unzip gave me an error that I don't have the right data type because the apiconnect returns a-gzip and not gzip