# Gzip decompression post request, axios, Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, backend

I'm doing a post request using axios in node.js.
The response is gzip data (behind, it's a huge json)

My goal is to read the json file behind the res (gzip).

Currently, my request is:

```
await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: process.env.API_URL + "/collection",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  },
  data: {
    project: req.body.project,
    platform: req.body.platform,
  },
  decompress: true,
}).then(async (response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

But I receive data like:

�1�����Q��:GR}��"-��}$K�ևҹ\��°<ܖqw�Vmp�������`Y!�����܋a�F�]� ���K%}0�`rЈ^�<��/�>
��Q���C7��R>�]§.,j�rg�6�MUVH��_Xq�����}|��a����$����K��cˠ��[�vv�����o�6�v�?~�����h���'Kn.��e��ZUW�;���ŗ��Ӹ׿6j%��M������Էʫ�c1��A�����.�t8�����Ș,����_��C�����۬���?q$޽@�CFq...

Does someone have any suggestion?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried placing `response.data` into the browser (e.g. a `span` element) instead of through `console`. Modern browsers automatically de-gzip.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a browser involved. Maybe the decompressing in axios doesn't work properly. Can you try [this answer with zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63858855/1948292).

Comment: It logs me: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 27 21 bb 61 00 ff ad 7c 69 93 22 57 92 ed 5f 79 56 ef 6b 5b 77 dc fd de fe c6 ce b0 59 b0 2f d3 cf c6 ee 4a 00 62 df 19 eb ff fe 3c 48 a5 ... 7877 more bytes> when I use 

zlib.gunzip(response, function (_err, output) {
              console.log(output.toString());
            });

Comment: @JMP, the fact is that I can't juste do that because I'm doing some processing after decompressing the answer...

Comment: Maybe you accidently compressed the file 2 times. Make sure there is no double-compressing happening.

Comment: the problem is that axios does not support brotli by default. 
Here's their reported issue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1635

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I want to get the information of my accessToken (from Google provider), then I can send a GET request like this:

```
const googleOauth2Url = `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=${accessToken}`;

const { data } = await axios.get(googleOauth2Url, {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        decompress: true,
      });
```

Then I receive the `data` that looks similar to yours. I investigate and find out that the `data` is compressed with `gzip`, then to use it we must decompress the `data`.

Now I use zlib.

```
zlib.gunzip(data, function (error, result) {
        console.log(result.toString());
        return result.toString();
      });
```

And the final result is:

```
{
  "issued_to": "some data,
  "audience": "some data",
  "user_id": "some id",
  "scope": "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  "expires_in": 2971,
  "email": "sample@gmail.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "access_type": "offline"
}
```