# NodeJs + ExpressJS response compression not working using compression()

Tags: node.js, express, compression

I have **Nodejs Project** with **ES6 Babel**. I want to compress my API response using compression but it is not working as it response with same amount of response with and without compression.

app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './route/index';
import compression from 'compression';

let app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(routes);
```

I don't know what is wrong with this.
I tried all the flags in compression as ***level**, **threshold** and **filter** but not succeed.

Comment: Please look into this https://medium.com/@victor.valencia.rico/gzip-compression-with-node-js-cc3ed74196f9

Comment: @Abhishek I already tried following simple example in demo app and it works but not working in my ES6 based node app. This simple example has all to gather in one file, I have my routes are in different file.

Comment: Does it not compressing  due to socket server ? @Abhishek

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308588/10030693